# How should we tag "The Wonderful End of the World"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[The game's homepage](http://dejobaan.com/wonderful/).

[Existing question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19593/is-it-possible-to-resize-fullscreen-the-window-in-the-wonderful-end-of-the-world) currently tagged as 'thewonderfulendoftheworld' (25 characters)

We can't use 'wonderful-end-of-the-world' because it's too long. (26 characters, the limit is 25)

Thoughts? Maybe [the-wonderful-end](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-wonderful-end)?

Comment: ***Why is it always 26 characters...***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[the-wonderful-end](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-wonderful-end)

A good place to start for these kinds of tags tends to be the main abbreviation of the game used for things like directories. In this case, the abbreviation is "wonderful", so it should be the central portion of the tag.

But just "wonderful" is... going to be terribly misleading. Like my opposition to "mukashi-mukashi-tokoro", I'm not too fond of [wonderful-end-of-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderful-end-of-world) skipping an article, so I'm thinking we just focus on the front of the game title, as you proposed initially.

Comment: [tag:wonderful-end-of-world] popped to mind immediately when I saw the question.

Answer (score -3):

[tweott](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tweott)

This sentence intentionally left useless for the sake of reaching 30 characters.

Comment: Thus missing an opportunity to document the pros and cons?

Comment: @Stuart Basically. I don't play the game nor do I feel strongly about it but wanted to throw the option out there.