# How should we tag El Shaddai: Ascension of the Metatron?

Tags: discussion, tags

It goes without saying that this title goes way past the 25 character limit. I don't think that using only [el-shaddai](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai) would be good because it's primarily a [biblical term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Shaddai) and searches for "El Shaddai" without the subtitle bring up primarly biblical references (and a few songs).

Right now, I'm leaning towards what we did with [Space Invaders Infinity Gene](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/how-should-we-tag-space-invaders-infinity-gene) and [The Wonderful End of the World](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/how-should-we-tag-the-wonderful-end-of-the-world) and tag it as [el-shaddai-ascension](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai-ascension) because [el-shaddai-ascension-metatron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai-ascension-metatron) is still too long.

Though the longest part of the name is a subtitle, as far as I know, there are currently no plans for a sequel, so I don't know if we should treat it the same as how we treat tagging series. I think using [el-shaddai-aotm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai-aotm) would be a poor decision, seeing as googling for "el shaddai aotm" brings up 4.5 million hits as opposed to "el shaddai ascension" which brings up 9.3 million.

Thoughts?

Comment: The thing is, people won't just google "el shaddai". [Then things become pretty specific.](http://www.google.it/search?q=el+shaddai+boss)

Comment: @badp Hm, what would you suggest then? Do you think just [tag:el-shaddai] would work or...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd be okay with the tag [el-shaddai](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai). I've never heard it called by its subtitle in regular conversation.

Comment: I agree with this. I've read a couple reviews of it, and I've never even heard of it's subtitle before this.

Comment: I realized that @badp made a really good point that people won't be searching for just the term itself, but in conjunction with problems specific to the game.

Answer (score 4):

Why not go with [ascension-of-the-metatron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascension-of-the-metatron)? Unless I've horribly failed at counting, that would be 25 characters exactly.

My googl'ing numbers show different amounts of hits than yours, but [Ascension of the Metatron](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ascenion%20of%20the%20metatron#hl=en&sa=X&ei=9TVtTuCrGeHq0gGo1b3hCA&ved=0CCEQvwUoAQ&q=ascension%20of%20the%20metatron&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=e7169cfc39072be&biw=1111&bih=548) has a little more than double that of [el shaddai ascension](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ascenion%20of%20the%20metatron#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=el%20shaddai%20ascension%20&pbx=1&oq=el%20shaddai%20ascension%20&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=22732l25507l1l26045l12l9l0l1l1l2l203l956l4.3.1l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=e7169cfc39072be&biw=1111&bih=548).

Comment: You count funny, Raven. ;) 12 mil is 1/3 more than 9 mill, not double 9 mill. Also, I didn't google for "ascension of the metatron," but for "el shaddai aotm," using the abbreviation method that we do for (some) series. My main concern with doing that is that people will start typing in [tag:el-shaddai], not [tag:ascension-of-the-metatron]. Would setting up a tag synonym between the two solve that problem?

Comment: @Fallen - I think our different locations around the world are affecting our google results. I have them at 6.4 mil and 3.2 mil respectively.

Comment: ...Wow, that is a *huge* disparity. I use google.com too, not .nl. How odd.

Comment: @Fallen - Yeah, and if you're using the links in my answer, we're pinging the same URL.

Comment: Never rely on the number Google says.  If you page through to the last page of results you'll see they're very inaccurate and sometimes find that there are actually more hits for the one with "fewer" results :P at least for smaller numbers, anyways.  BTW I get 30 mil for `"Ascension of the Metatron"` and 11 mil for `"El Shaddai Ascension"` :P.

Answer (score -1):

How about [el-shaddai-asc-metatron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/el-shaddai-asc-metatron)? As far as I am aware, "asc." is generally accepted as an abbreviation for ascent/ascension (like "desc." for descent).