# How should we tag Kingdom Hearts: Birth By Sleep?

Tags: discussion, tags

Kingdom Hearts: Birth By Sleep is yet another title that blows past our tag limit (not suprising given the series' [penchant for long/weird naming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33899/kingdom-hearts-timeline/33913#33913)). I'd asked it last year and forgot to ask another (gaming ADD hit again...) so it became untagged.

Since we've [talked](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/how-should-we-tag-space-invaders-infinity-gene) [about](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/how-should-we-tag-prince-of-persia) [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games) [a lot](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1995/how-should-we-tag-the-wonderful-end-of-the-world) and decided to deal with it on a case by case basis.

We have hardly any Kingdom Hearts questions here, likely because most of the main releases came out before the site's existence. The next title will be *Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance* in spring 2012, so we should probably decide on a convention for abbreviation before then.

So should we go for:

- [kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs) with the full title in the tag wiki, like we do with other games with potentially unclear abbrevations? This is what I'd previously tagged it with before.
- [kh-birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kh-birth-by-sleep) - I'm always loathe to start off with the abbreviations for series whose abbreviations aren't as strong as stuff like Prince of Persia's or Modern Warfare's. I suppose we could alleviate that with [kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs) as a synonym?
- [kingdom-hearts-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-series) and [birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-by-sleep) - we've the dual tagging system now, the continued existence of which [is up in the air](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/why-are-questions-adding-the-top-two-tags-to-the-title), but this could be an option.

Thoughts?

Comment: My vote for kh-birth-by-sleep.  I think this series is only likely to have longer and sillier subtitles as it goes on.

Comment: I think 31 would have been a better tag limit (just like the old Mac OS file limit ;) ).

Comment: [As of December 10, 2017](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12736/181240), this tag has been renamed to [tag:kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most important aspects of the tagging system for Gaming is the fact that it shows up in the title in Google searches.

Like you said, *Kingdom Hearts* games aren't really known by their subtitle like *Call of Duty* or *The Elder Scrolls* is: people generally say, "I got that new *Kingdom Hearts* game," not "I got *Birth By Sleep*".

Given that, I think the master tag must include `kingdom-hearts`, this would mean the tag would be [kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs).

`bbs` is ambiguous, but what's cool about the tag selector is that it mentions other synonyms for the tag. So if a synonym is set up as [kh-birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kh-birth-by-sleep) or even [birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-by-sleep), the tag selector will say:

> [kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs)
>   This is the tag wiki excerpt.
>   <sub>Also: kh-birth-by-sleep, birth-by-sleep</sub>

Which should alleviate any ambiguity.

Comment: If I need information about a game, I wouldn't table in the series title, I'd type in birth by sleep so kingdom-hearts-bbs would fall further down the google rankings.

Comment: @danRhul The premise of the question is that "Kingdom Hearts" takes precedence over the game subtitle, so your personal habits would be anecdotal when compared to how most people playing the game use the title. But either way Google is smart enough to detect context.

Comment: True it would be picked up, but it would be so far down the pecking order, its pretty pointless.