# Expand abbreviated Kingdom Hearts tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-rename-request

There are two tags under the Kingdom Hearts games which contain the abbreviated title, which were created prior to the increased limit of 35 characters.

Can the following tags be renamed?

[kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs) -> [kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep)

[kingdom-hearts-com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-com) -> [kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories)

Comment: Someone with permissions and time should really look into our tags. It seems like a lot of them are abbreviated but now can be fixed with the expanded tag limit.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud While that may be a good idea, I think asking meta posts is adequate enough. Going through each tag would require a lot of time and patience, and include excess research if the one who does it is unfamiliar with a title to determine if it's really abbreviated or not. By asking meta posts, we have multiple users going through the tags and asking for rename requests as they see fit

Comment: @Robotnik You appear to handle rename requests often, what are your thoughts on my previous comment?

Comment: Fair enough, as I know I certainly wouldn't want to spend hours lost in the tag forest of death.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud & Wondercricket - There's no need to get them all changed *immediately*, raising Meta questions as you come across them is the best approach, we can slowly fix them up piecemeal. I'm actually glad the community is raising these metas. It'd be very time consuming for a single person to find abbreviations and check what the expanded name is; I certainly don't know every game's full name when I see them. So keep it up! I can action these fairly easily when I get a spare moment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done:

- [kingdom-hearts-bbs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-bbs) -> [kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep)
- [kingdom-hearts-com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-com) -> [kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories)